# IOS/Objective-C: Center Line under Button Programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, line

I am trying to do a simple line under three buttons to create a Tabs effect. While I could do this in Storyboard, I'd like to do it in code and ideally make the line a subview of an element already in the view to avoid having to give it special constraints.

My approach has been to create a UILabel with no text and a background color.  I can make the UILabel a subview of the View, however, that does not attach it to the bottom of the buttons.

On the other hand, if I make the UILabel a subview of one of the buttons, I can't see it.

Can anyone suggest a simple way to do this?

```
[centerButton setTitle:@"Favorites" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 120, 280, 2)];
            label.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
            label.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
             label.numberOfLines = 1;
             label.text = @"";
            [self.view addSubview: label];
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

**Edit:**

I tried adding some NSLayoutConstraints Programmatically:

```
    NSLayoutConstraint *con3 = [NSLayoutConstraint
                                constraintWithItem:label attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:centerButton
                                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1 constant:0];

    [label addConstraints:@[con3]];
//tried with and without
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

This returned the exception:

```
     [LayoutConstraints] The view hierarchy is not prepared
 for the constraint: <NSLayoutConstraint:0x174e85500 V:
[UIButton:0x100b0baf0'Now']-(0)-[UILabel:0x108555160] 
  (inactive)>
        When added to a view, the constraint's items
 must be descendants of that view (or the view itself). 
This will crash if the constraint needs to be resolved 
before the view hierarchy is assembled. 
Break on -[UIView(UIConstraintBasedLayout) 
_viewHierarchyUnpreparedForConstraint:] to debug.
```

The button created in storyboard is a subview of self.view and I add the label to self.view as a subview in code so not sure why the exception is occurring.

Comment: Frame math is pretty old-school at this point for this kind of thing. I'd definitely try out constraints.

Comment: The view is pretty complicated with lots of storyboard auto layout constraints.  Just hoping to assign the line to something already constrained so as not to have to redo a lot of existing constraints

Comment: Do you want the line "animated" from one "tab button" to the selected one? Or do you just want a line to show up?

Comment: Alternatively, you could try a `UISegmentedControl` subclass and just adapt the way it looks. It will take care of the layout itself.

Comment: Using constraints would be easier to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DonMag.  Just show up in correct place is fine.  I can manually place in self.view but would like to tie it to some elements that are part of the auto layout scheme in storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wonder from the error message if you're possibly attempting to add the NSLayoutConstraint prior to the redLabel view being added to it's parentView (or too early in the lifecycle).  In any event, I think this is pretty close to what you're attempting to accomplish:

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nullable) UILabel *previousRedLabel;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        UIView *buttonSuperview = [clickedButton superview];
        if (buttonSuperview != nil) {
            [self _putRedLineWithHeight:3.0f atTheBottomOfView:buttonSuperview animate:YES];
        }
    }
}

- (void)_putRedLineWithHeight:(CGFloat)height atTheBottomOfView:(UIView *)viewToPutUnder animate:(BOOL)animate {
    // remove our previous red line
    if (self.previousRedLabel) {
        // if you want it to be a no-op here if they click the same button
        // you'll need to add some logic to check if the superView == viewToPutUnder
        [self.previousRedLabel removeFromSuperview];
        self.previousRedLabel = nil;
    }
    UILabel *redLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    // we're using autolayout so we don't want any resizing from it
    redLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    redLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // start out with alpha = 0
    redLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
    // add it to our parentView
    [viewToPutUnder addSubview:redLabel];
    // height (determined by passed in value)
    NSAssert(height >= 0, @"Height must be a positive number");
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:height];
    // width equal to parentView's width
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewToPutUnder attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // center x == parentView's center x
    NSLayoutConstraint *centerConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewToPutUnder attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // now the bottom constraint (place it at the bottom of the parent view)
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:viewToPutUnder attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // add the height constraint to our label
    [redLabel addConstraint:heightConstraint];
    // and all the other constraints to our parent view
    [viewToPutUnder addConstraints:@[widthConstraint, centerConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
    redLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    if (animate) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f animations:^{
            [redLabel layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
    self.previousRedLabel = redLabel;
}
```

Example of Animated:

[image]

And one of Non-Animated:

[image]

**EDITED ANSWER TO HANDLE THE CASE IF EACH BUTTON ISN'T IN IT'S OWN SUPERVIEW**

Adjusted for if all buttons are in one superview (width based on button width, center to button center, and pinning the top of the label to the bottom of the button)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()
@property (strong, nullable) UILabel *previousRedLabel;
- (void)_putRedLineWithHeight:(CGFloat)height atTheBottomOfButton:(UIButton *)button animate:(BOOL)animate;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (IBAction)buttonClicked:(id)sender {
    if ([sender isKindOfClass:[UIButton class]]) {
        UIButton *clickedButton = (UIButton *)sender;
        // if you want it to be a no-op here if they click the same button
        // you'll need to add some logic to store the previous clicked button and check whether it's the same button
        [self _putRedLineWithHeight:3.0f atTheBottomOfButton:clickedButton animate:YES];
    }
}

- (void)_putRedLineWithHeight:(CGFloat)height atTheBottomOfButton:(UIButton *)button animate:(BOOL)animate {
    UIView *buttonSuperview = button.superview;
    NSAssert(buttonSuperview != nil, @"Button has to have a superview");
    // remove our previous red line
    if (self.previousRedLabel) {
        [self.previousRedLabel removeFromSuperview];
        self.previousRedLabel = nil;
    }
    UILabel *redLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    // we're using autolayout so we don't want any resizing from it
    redLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
    redLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    // start out with alpha = 0
    redLabel.alpha = 0.0f;
    // add it to our parentView
    [buttonSuperview addSubview:redLabel];
    // height (determined by passed in value)
    NSAssert(height >= 0, @"Height must be a positive number");
    NSLayoutConstraint *heightConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:nil attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute multiplier:1.0f constant:height];
    // width equal to button's width
    NSLayoutConstraint *widthConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // center x == button's center x
    NSLayoutConstraint *centerConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // now pin the top of the label to the bottom of the button
    NSLayoutConstraint *bottomConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:redLabel attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom multiplier:1.0f constant:0.0f];
    // add the height constraint to our label
    [redLabel addConstraint:heightConstraint];
    // and all the other constraints to our parent view
    [buttonSuperview addConstraints:@[widthConstraint, centerConstraint, bottomConstraint]];
    redLabel.alpha = 1.0f;
    if (animate) {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.6f animations:^{
            [redLabel layoutIfNeeded];
        }];
    }
    self.previousRedLabel = redLabel;
}


@end
```

Animated:

[image]

Not Animated:

[image]

Comment: That’s assuming you have each of the buttons in their own superview.  I’ll edit my answer in a bit to show if all 3 buttons are in the same superview